# R: Subsetting rows by group based on time difference

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have the following data frame:

```
group_id   date_show   date_med
1          1976-02-07  1971-04-14
1          1976-02-09  1976-12-11
1          2011-03-02  1970-03-22
2          1993-08-04  1997-06-13
2          2008-07-25  2006-09-01
2          2009-06-18  2005-11-12
3          2009-06-18  1999-11-03
```

I want to subset my data frame in such a way that the new data frame only shows the rows in which the values of `date_show` are further than 10 days apart but this condition should only be applied per group. I.e. if the values in the `date_show` column are less than 10 days apart but the `group_id`s are different, I need to keep both entries. What I want my result to look like based on the above table is:

```
group_id   date_show   date_med
1          1976-02-07  1971-04-14
1          2011-03-02  1970-03-22
2          1993-08-04  1997-06-13
2          2008-07-25  2006-09-01
2          2009-06-18  2005-11-12
3          2009-06-18  1999-11-03
```

Which row gets deleted isn't important because the reason why I'm subsetting in the first place is to calculate the number of rows I am left with after applying this criteria.

I've tried playing around with the `diff` function but I'm not sure how to go about it in the simplest possible way because this problem is already within another sapply function so I'm trying to avoid any kind of additional loop (in this case by `group_id`).

The df I'm working with has around 100 000 rows. Ideally, I would like to do this with base R because I have no rights to install any additional packages on the machine I'm working on but if this is not possible (or if solving this with an additional package would be significantly better), I can try and ask my admin to install it.

Any tips would be appreciated!

Comment: Without external packages you might have to resort to some standard split/apply/combine approach a la `df <- df[order(df$group_id, df$date_show),]; do.call(rbind, lapply(split(df, df$group_id), function(d) d[c(TRUE, diff(d$date_show) >= 10),]))`

Comment: @docendo discimus I finally managed to solve it with some merging and splitting. I'd never used `split` before but after successfully getting to the intervals I needed, it turned out to be just the thing I was looking for! Thanks for taking the time to answer this!